# Members' site in Craft possible out of the box?

Tags: craft-pro

I built a site in another CMS with an add-on which allows entries to be converted to member bios, and another add-on which makes sure all files uploaded by different members are viewable to that member only. The site allows users to search bands and read band profiles/listen to demos (Mp3s), each Member (band) uses a front end publish page to create their profiles (bios), would this workflow be possible using Craft?

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

- In Craft, all Elements — including Users — can have custom fields of their own. (So, for example, each User could have a "Bio" field.) You can use a [User Profile Form](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/user-profile-form) to allow Users to edit their own profiles.
- You can [restrict the upload directory](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields#restricting-uploads-to-a-single-folder) for each Assets field. So, for example, you could create an Assets field that stores files in a directory based on each User's ID, which would effectively keep one User from viewing/disturbing another User's files.